# How to create my own wallet and own blockchain explorer?

Tags: web3js, wallets, ubuntu, explorers, api-design

I'm running my own private/permissioned ethereum blockchain via geth on Ubuntu. How can i interact with my blockchain to visualize accounts, blocks, transactions etc...?

I've tried a lot of tutorials but many didnt show me any information via some web. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Ethereum Stack Exchange! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Are you looking for a wallet with graphical user interface or a blockchain explorer? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks and will do going forward. I'm actually looking for both :) Interacting with the BC via the CLI is no problem, but for any user without access to the CLI there's kind of a need for some apps either via a browser or as a real executable. So on one side users should see a) their account with some sort of wallet and b) see the BC working in general i.e. a blockchain explorer. We are hosting everything internally for Dev purposes. Does this clarify a bit? Thanks